# display image by click somewhere in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I want to create website like this: https://davidgomezmaestre.com/?nav=1

when you click somewhere without button, you see a pic and also background color is depends on pic.

I'm gonna create my own website with Squarespace but I couldn't find how to do that. please help me (:

I tried to find original codes from the example site but actually coding is not my job, and I couldn't do it.

Comment: Do you want the changes to happen when you click on something, or on hover like the website you linked?

Comment: i want it happen when I click on anywhere in page. it's random. I guess you looking at menu.

Comment: Ah I see. The website is loading images with the plugin "imagesLoaded" - here's a link to the devs website, it should help you get started https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: thank you. but how can I use this plugin?

Comment: I overestimated how difficult it was to do. While the webpage you linked does use the plugin, it's possible to do without. See my answer.

Comment: Hi again :/ in the morning, I made it. but now, I can't see the result even though I embedded the code. I'm using these codes in Squarespace by the way. please can we check together if you have time.

Comment: I haven't used squarespace before but I can definitely take a look for you. Do you have a link?

Comment: well I guess I can't share the link without making my site private. can you text me when you are available please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

- adding an `array` for your images,
- creating a new element with a `click event`,
- inserting images from the array into said element.

Then do the same for the background-color by making an `array` of colors and changing the `<body>` CSS with a `click event`.

```js
var counter = 0;

var bgColor = [
  "#e8dff5", // color array for background-color
  "#fce1e4",
  "#fcf4dd",
  "#ddedea"
];

var imgArray = [
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqweJ.png", //add URLs for your images here
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFC7W.png",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjZch.png",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ALBl.png"
];


container.onclick = function(e) { //add images on click-event

  if (counter == bgColor.length) counter = 0; //loop background colors
  if (counter == imgArray.length) counter = 0; //loop images

  document.body.style.background = bgColor[counter]; //change background 

  var pic = document.createElement('img'); //create new element 
  pic.src = imgArray[counter]; //add URL for images
  pic.classList.add("image"); //add class name for images
  pic.style.position = 'absolute';
  pic.style.top = e.clientY + 'px'; //place images where you click
  pic.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  this.appendChild(pic);
  counter++;
}


reset = document.querySelector(".reset") //remove images on click-event
reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.image').forEach(function(x) {
    x.remove();
  })
})
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100vw; /* makes whole page clickable, make smaller if need */
  height: 100vh;
}

.image {
  width: 100px;  /* style your images here */
  height:100px;
}

.reset { 
  position: fixed; /* click to remove images */
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 999999; /* ensure reset isn't hidden behind images */
  cursor: pointer; /* indicates element is clickable */
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<div class="reset">REMOVE IMAGES</div>
```